# Vuejs 2.0 attribute not showing in page source

Tags: html, templates, vuejs2

In Vue 1.0.28 I can do something like this:

```
Vue.component('singletext', {
      template: `<input type=text value="{{item.value}}" />`,
      props: {
          item: Object
      }
});
```

and get this when I view the page source:

```
<input type="text" value="a value">
```

But in Vue 2.0, I must use v-bind, which properly shows the value on the screen, but the page source is missing the attribute like this:

```
Vue.component('singletext', {
      template: `<input type=text :value="item.value" />`,
      props: {
          item: Object
      }
});
```

Page source:

```
<input type="text">
```

Is there anyway to ensure the page source is generated properly? (without SSR)

Comment: I'm curious why you need it. There's no way I know of to do so.

Comment: @Bert playing with making an html form generator, need to capture the output and save for future use.

Comment: How should it render? Should it be `value="<value of item.value>"` or literally `value="item.value"`?

Comment: @Marty v-model doesn't seem to work either

Comment: @Bert it should be value="<value of item.value>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a render function works.

```
Vue.component("singletext", {
  props:{item: Object},
  render(h){
   return h('input', {attrs: {value: this.item.value, type: "text"}})
  }
})
```

I can't think of a better way to do it. If you need more template like features, you can [add them](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Replacing-Template-Features-with-Plain-JavaScript).

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/vJbOLV?editors=1010).

Comment: Hmm, this could get ugly. Was hoping I finally had a good use case to learn Vuejs, but Handlebars might be a better tool for this task.

Comment: @AndrewGrothe I wish I had a better answer for you. Basically bind and vmodel aren't concerned with rendering the actual value attribute AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, understood. On the other hand, it was super easy to setup so other than my weird use-case, everything was very nice.